# Materials fail to export to babylon.js

Tags: export, pbr, webgl

After baking my textures (the left window is in material view, not render) I attempted to export to babylon.js (built on top of three.js):

[image]

I did not use any kind of checker pattern in my material--rather, I applied a different material to the dark and light squares and a third one to the grout:

[image]

So, it can't be a UV issue since there was no actual checker textures to begin with. I think the checker pattern on the right may be some default texture for babylon.js, but I'm not sure.

Has anyone got this process to work?

**EDIT**

Here's the javascript that loads the .babylon file into the scene:

```
BABYLON.SceneLoader.Append("", "babylon\\checkerboard2.79.babylon", scene, function (scene) {});
```

Comment: It may be worth trying to file a bug on BabylonJS if the exporter is not working as expected. Alternatively, you could export to glTF — BabylonJS can import it natively, it supports PBR, and Blender 2.8 has an exporter built in. Then at least you can test the model in other viewers and determine if the bug is in the export process or the library.

Comment: Minor: ThreeJS and BabylonJS are separate libraries, so I'm removing the `three.js` tag here.